# Error while connecting MYSQL with asp.net core

Tags: mysql, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-2.0

## Problem

I am trying to conect MY SQL with my asp.net core 2.0 web application. But it throug me this error

> Method 'Clone' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.Internal.MySQLOptionsExtension' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=6.10.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.

I am using Repository pattern  in asp.net core 2.0 with EF 2.0

## startup.cs

here the error occurs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
            options.UseMySQL(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("AspNetCoreMultipleProject")
                ));
```

Comment: looks like you can't use the "clone" method with this library

Comment: any thing which helps me. I am using mysql with asp.net core very first time and I already searched a lot but not find any thing good

Comment: Can you include the code where this error is occurring?

Comment: @majita question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this could be because the official MySQL provider doesn't work with EF core 2.0 - [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10065).

The suggested workaround is to use the Pomelo provider - [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/pomelo/)

Comment: I changed it to UseMySql but now it show me this error
> "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."